# Can i play songs from document directory with iPodMusicPlayer in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am using `iPodMusicPlayer` to play songs from iPod Library.
Now i want to play songs from document directory with `iPodMusicPlayer`.

I don't want to play with `AVPlayer`.

If i can , how can i play it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can. Try checking out this Apple document: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html